# How do you set debug=true in web.config when using configSource

Tags: debugging, web-config

I am using VS 2013 I set debug=true in web.config and get the following error.

A section using 'configSource' may contain no other attributes or elements

My web.config looks like this

Comment: This is the error message I'm getting

Comment: Parser Error Message: A section using 'configSource' may contain no other attributes or elements.

Source Error: 


Line 56: 
Line 57:   <system.web>
Line 58:   <compilation configSource="App_Configuration\SystemWeb_Compilation.config" debug="true" />    
Line 59:   <pages configSource="App_Configuration\SystemWeb_Pages.config" />
Line 60:   <roleManager configSource="App_Configuration\SystemWeb_RoleManager.config" />

Comment: I want to use configurationSource and debug together like this <compilation configSource="App_Configuration\SystemWeb_Compilation.config" debug="true" /> web.config doesn't like them in the same tag, how can I use both debug and configurationSource

Comment: I solved the problem by putting debug=true in the compilation tag and moved the configsource to a seperate tag as follows ----------------------------<code><compilation  debug="true" />
    <clientTarget configSource="App_Configuration\SystemWeb_Compilation.config" /></code>